# How to store javascript code in database?

Tags: javascript, database, countdown

I created a webshop for an online game where the users can buy in-game stuff. I have some special items which will be only availabe for a short period of time and I want to print out how much time left to buy it.

I wrote a JS code to countdown for a date, and now I want to store it in the database. Which is the best way to do it? Just a varchart with extremely long length? Or is it a more elegant way to deal with this?

Comment: this question is quite broad. Have you tried anything? Did you run into problems?

Comment: i tried it and works for me but I want to know if its a better way to do it or not

Comment: Why do you want to store javascript code in your db ? Just store the end date.

Comment: Just store the timestamp and then you can easily convert to your desired format

Comment: Well, it was pretty trivial, I'm a bit tired I guess. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Function.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) method to convert a function into a string and then later use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) to execute the function.

You should use `text` type rather than `varchar` as it will likely be longer than maximum `varchar` length.

However, I would strongly discourage you to do this. A better approach would be to store something like a expiration date `timestamp` and calculate the availability based on that value.